# Grep regex result not as expected?

Tags: regex, grep, freebsd, sh

Using FreeBSD 11.1:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

if printf 'abcde.fgh' | grep -iEq '^[^][$^*_-]'; then
    echo "test 1 success"
else
    echo "test 1 fail"
fi

echo

if printf 'abcde.fgh' | grep -iEq '^[^][.$^*_-]'; then
    echo "test 2 success"
else
    echo "test 2 fail"
fi
```

Output:

```bsh
test 1 success

grep: Unmatched [ or [^
test 2 fail
```

But AFAICT these should give the same result. They both contain a condition on the first character (only), that it isn't one of a list of specified non-alphabetic characters. Breakdown of the regex:

- `^` = start of string
- `[^...]` = match if none of these characters
- Within the list, `]` must be the first character, `^` must not be the first, and - must be the last. So `][.^$_-` is a valid list of literal characters and the string mustn't match any of them.
- To avoid confusion note that this means the `][` are literal `"]"` and `"["` chars in the list, **not** a close-and-reopen of 2 lists.

The only difference between the 2 expressions is the `"."` but it's inside a list, so it should be treated as `not literal .` and indeed the first char doesn't match literal `"."`

What am I missing? Something very obvious and simple, probably?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a few other syntax rules. Within a bracket expansion, in addition to plain ranges, there are also a few types of multi-character expressions which start with a `[`. (See the *regex(7)* manual for [Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html) or [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=re_format&sektion=7&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+11.2-RELEASE+and+Ports) at "With the exception of these **and some combinations using '['** (see next paragraphs)".) These are:

- Collating elements: `[.` … `.]`
- Equivalence classes: `[=` … `=]`
- Character classes: `[:` … `:]`

(You might have seen or used such expressions as `[[:digit:]]` – these are actually a character class `[:digit:]` that happens to be the lone element of a `[…]` bracket expansion.)

So in your case, since the `.` happens to be immediately after a `[`, they are recognized as the opening delimiter of a collating element. GNU grep 3.1 has the correct error message:

```
$ printf 'abcde.fgh' | grep -iEq '^[^][.$^*_-]'
grep: Unmatched [, [^, [:, [., or [=
```

The same expressions can be used to escape such situations by using e.g. `[...]` or `[=.=]` to include a regular dot, or similarly `[=-=]` to match a dash, if there is nowhere to move them.

Comment: Ahhh. Makes sense. I wasn't looking out for other multicharacter class syntax that it might resemble, so that was way off my horizons. Thanks!